# b2body is not showing in b2world- Box2D

Tags: android, box2d, cocos2d-x

```
b2BodyDef myBodyDef;
myBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
myBodyDef.position.Set(_screenSize.width / 3, _screenSize.height / 3);
myBodyDef.angle = 0; 
b2Body* dynamicBody = m_world->CreateBody(&myBodyDef);
b2PolygonShape boxShape;
boxShape.SetAsBox(10, 10);

PTM_RATIO = 40.0f;
m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO);
m_world->SetDebugDraw(m_debugDraw);

b2FixtureDef boxFixtureDef;
boxFixtureDef.shape = &boxShape;
boxFixtureDef.density = 1;
dynamicBody->CreateFixture(&boxFixtureDef);
```

I am using box2d in cocos2d-x 2.2.1

and using this  simple code to show a b2body in the screen but for using the

```
m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO);
```

I am getting

```
Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:164: error: undefined reference to 'GLESDebugDraw::GLESDebugDraw(float)'
```

i am doing with their reference project only but i couldnt find why the object is not showing in the screen.

And if i am not declaring the value for the PTM_RATIO , it is giving error as

```
PTM_RATIO value was not declared in this scope.
```

### UPDATE : 1:

By including the GLES_Render.cpp in my android.mk file the error related to the PTM_RATIO Is cleared.

### UPDATE : 2:

this is my draw method code

```
void HelloWorld::draw() {
//
// IMPORTANT:
// This is only for debug purposes
// It is recommend to disable it
//
CCLayer::draw();

ccGLEnableVertexAttribs (kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position);

kmGLPushMatrix();

m_world->DrawDebugData();

kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```

### UPDATE : 3:

My final code:

My android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/GLES_Render.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
                /home/user/adt/cocos2dx/external/Box2D \
                /home/user/adt/cocos2dx/external


LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos_testcpp_common
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += chipmunk_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libcurl)
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android)
$(call import-module,extensions)
$(call import-module,external/Box2D)
$(call import-module,external/chipmunk)
```

and this is how i defined the b2world

```
m_world = new b2World(gravity);
m_world->SetAllowSleeping(true);
m_world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);
m_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO);
m_world->SetDebugDraw(m_debugDraw);
uint32 flags = 0;
flags += b2Draw::e_shapeBit;
//  flags += b2Draw::e_jointBit;
/*flags += b2Draw::e_aabbBit;
 flags += b2Draw::e_pairBit;
 flags += b2Draw::e_centerOfMassBit;*/
m_debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);
```

then in a menu sprite click callback method i am using this to show a b2body

```
b2BodyDef myBodyDef;
myBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody; //this will be a dynamic body
myBodyDef.position.Set(_screenSize.width / 3, _screenSize.height / 3);
//set the starting position
myBodyDef.angle = 0; //set the starting angle
b2Body* dynamicBody = m_world->CreateBody(&myBodyDef);
dynamicBody->SetType(b2_staticBody);
b2PolygonShape boxShape;
boxShape.SetAsBox(200, 200);

b2FixtureDef boxFixtureDef;
boxFixtureDef.shape = &boxShape;
boxFixtureDef.density = 1;
dynamicBody->CreateFixture(&boxFixtureDef);
```

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong . i couldn't find it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `android.mk` you have to add `GLESDebugDraw.cpp` and also include `GLESDebugDraw.h` in your .cpp file where you are using it.

If you want to debug draw then you have to write only these line in the your draw method

```
CCLayer::draw();
ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );

kmGLPushMatrix();

world->DrawDebugData();

kmGLPopMatrix();
```

In your init method or constructor

```
debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO);
world->SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);

uint32 flags = 0;
flags += b2Draw::e_shapeBit;
//  flags += b2Draw::e_jointBit;
/*flags += b2Draw::e_aabbBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_pairBit;
    flags += b2Draw::e_centerOfMassBit;*/
debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);
```

Try this, This is my init method............

```
    bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }



    this->setTouchEnabled(true);

    CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();
    array2->createWithCapacity(4);

    b2Vec2 gravity;
    gravity.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
    _world = new b2World(gravity);
    _world->SetContactListener(this);

       // Do we want to let bodies sleep?
    _world->SetAllowSleeping(false);

    _world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);

    _debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO);
    _world->SetDebugDraw(_debugDraw);



      uint32 flags = 0;
      flags += b2Draw::e_shapeBit;
    //      flags += b2Draw::e_jointBit;
    //      flags += b2Draw::e_aabbBit;
    //      flags += b2Draw::e_pairBit;
    //      flags += b2Draw::e_centerOfMassBit;
          _debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);


    /////////////////////////////
    // 2. add a menu item with "X" image, which is clicked to quit the program
    //    you may modify it.

    // add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
    CCMenuItemImage *pCloseItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
                                        "CloseNormal.png",
                                        "CloseSelected.png",
                                        this,
                                        menu_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback));

    pCloseItem->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width - pCloseItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                                origin.y + pCloseItem->getContentSize().height/2));

    // create menu, it's an autorelease object
    CCMenu* pMenu = CCMenu::create(pCloseItem, NULL);
    pMenu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
    this->addChild(pMenu, 1);

    /////////////////////////////
    // 3. add your codes below...

    // add a label shows "Hello World"
    // create and initialize a label

    CCLabelTTF* pLabel = CCLabelTTF::create("Hello World", "Arial", 24);

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    pLabel->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                            origin.y + visibleSize.height - pLabel->getContentSize().height));

    // add the label as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(pLabel, 1);

    // add "HelloWorld" splash screen"
    CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create("HelloWorld.png");

    // position the sprite on the center of the screen
    pSprite->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));

    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
//    this->addChild(pSprite, 0);

    plbdy();

    schedule(SEL_SCHEDULE(&HelloWorld::update), 0);
    return true;
}
```

This is my `plbdy()`

```
plbdy()
{
b2BodyDef bdf ;

    bdf.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(1,1);
    b2FixtureDef fd;
    fd.shape = &shape;
    fd.density = 1;

b2Body hero = _world->CreateBody(&bdf2);
    hero->CreateFixture(&fd);
}
```

And This is my Box2d update method to update world

```
update(float dt)
{
int velocityIterations = 8;
    int positionIterations = 1;
_world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
}
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
Try these make a simple body nothing more and then check body is created or not
```

Comment: i have not included the GLES_Render.cpp in my andorid.mk, after  i included that the "GLESDebugDraw" error related to PTM_RATIO is refined. but i didnt get the object on the screen

Comment: #define PTM_RATIO 40   use this

Comment: i dont know why i am not getting anything on the screen . other sprites are showing but the box2d object only not showing with ur updated ans too.

Comment: post you code then i will see it tomarro  include GLESDebugDraw.h in hello.h also may it work for you

Comment: please see my update 3 i have updated my code. no error is coming now. but the object also not showing

Comment: You get my updated answer chk it then tell is it working

Comment: thanks for ur code. but nothing shown for me. i think i have some problem in my execution of this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is:

```
Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:164: error: undefined reference to 'GLESDebugDraw::GLESDebugDraw(float)'
```

It looks like your GLESDebugDraw is not defined.  Did you include the class header file?

Comment: i have not included the GLES_Render.cpp in my andorid.mk, after  i included that the "GLESDebugDraw" error related to PTM_RATIO is refined. but i didnt get the object on the screen

Answer (score 0):

GLES_Render.cpp needs to be added to android.mk file. I have added to the mk file and it works with full debugdraw. Below is where I have included the PTM_RATIO in my hello world

```
    #ifndef __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
    #define __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__

    #include "cocos2d.h"
    #include "Box2D/Box2D.h"
    #include "ContactListener.h"
    #include "GLES-Render.h"


    #define PTM_RATIO 32

    class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer
    {
           public:
```

Comment: you can view my .mk file here in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641945/android-cocos2d-x-2-2-box2d-setup

Comment: also change the GLES_Render class ... you can use mine instead... pm me with your email address and I will send it across