# android cocos2d-x 2.2 box2d setup

Tags: android, eclipse, box2d, cocos2d-x

I have made a cross platform box2d cocos2d-x project and it works on ios and blackberry but I am not able to get it to work on android. I have looked at tutorials and all of them are from 2.15 and before. I added all the debug code in android.mk and I still get errors related anything to box2d saying it cannot be resolved

```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

   LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/B2DebugDrawLayer.cpp \
               ../../Classes/ContactListener.cpp \
               ../../Classes/GB2SHapeCache-x.cpp \
               ../../Classes/GLES-Render.cpp 

   LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
                /home/user/siddharthshekar/Documents/_Projects/cocos2d-x-   2.2_master/external


   LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
   LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
   LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
   LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += chipmunk_static
   LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

   $(call import-module,cocos2dx)
   $(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libcurl)
   $(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) 
   $(call import-module,extensions) 
   $(call import-module,external/Box2D) 
   $(call import-module,external/chipmunk)
```

Comment: ok it works now with the above android.mk file with complete debug draw. just close and restart eclipse for reference sake below is the application.mk file

        APP_STL := gnustl_static
        APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti  -DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1 -DUSE_BOX2D -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1

Comment: @BadLuckBrian: you still having same problem?

Comment: No , i got it to work

Comment: good.   what is this 15 character bs.. lol.